# DAX - sum column based on multiple containsstring

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Using the table attached as an example 'Financial_Tab'.

I want to sum [Budget] based on whether "1.2.4" is within [CBS Code], and where "NOP1" or "NOP2" or "NOP3" is within [CBS Name]. Returning £50 in the example table.

[image: Table Example]

I'm struggling looking for a succinct and functional way of searching for NOP1/NOP2/NOP3 in one go. I'm returning blank results. I think IN {} could be used but I cant get it to work with containsstring.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
Sum Budget = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Budget]),
    CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[CBS Code], "1.2.4"),
    CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[CBS Name], "NOP1")
    || CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[CBS Name], "NOP2")
    || CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[CBS Name], "NOP3")
)
```

Comment: If you would've been smart enough to provide copyable sample data I could've proven that this measure solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter, worked a charm. I'm not very smart, hence the basic question, and lack of sample data (first post and could not find a place to upload a csv). For instances where there are many searches in the same column (NOP1 through to NOP20 etc.) do you know if we can incorporate the IN function to make it more succinct? Thanks again